# My Date picker is returning the wrong value for minutes and Seconds

Tags: ios, objective-c, datepicker, nsdate, nsdateformatter

My Date Picker is returning the wrong value for the minute and seconds but the hour works fine. Here's my method for getting it.

```
-(NSDate *)datePickerTime
{
NSCalendar *gregorianCalendar = [[NSCalendar alloc]initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
[gregorianCalendar setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone localTimeZone]];
NSDateFormatter *format = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[format setDateFormat:@"HH:mm:ss"];
[format setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone localTimeZone]];
NSString *dateString =[format stringFromDate:[self.timePicker date]];
NSDate *adjustedDate = [format dateFromString:dateString];
NSDateComponents *comp = [[NSDateComponents alloc]init];

comp = [gregorianCalendar components:(NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit) fromDate:adjustedDate];

reminderTime = [gregorianCalendar dateFromComponents:comp];

return reminderTime;
}
```

Comment: U r code is not clear. let us known ur requirement clearly..

Comment: what is wrong with the value?

Comment: the hours value is correct but the minutes is wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check the best [Apple sample code](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/DatePicker/Listings/MyWindowController_m.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS10004134-MyWindowController_m-DontLinkElementID_4) of Date picker with all type of format support!

Your problem might be in [setDateFormat ISO-8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Dates)

try this code

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

[formatter setDateFormat:@"hh:mm:ss a"];

NSLog(@"Current Date: %@", [formatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]]);

[formatter release];
```

Comment: I'm not after the current date, I need the date from my date picker. i.e the date the person chooses. My code returns the right hours value but not the right minutes value. any help?

Answer (score 0):

in my Application I get correct time by the following

```
NSDate *endDate = [NSDate date];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter2 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter2 setDateFormat:@"HH:mm:ss"];
NSString* curdatestr = [dateFormatter2 stringFromDate:endDate];
NSLog(@"str%@",curdatestr);
```

if you also want date with current time use

```
[dateFormatter2 setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd 'at' HH:mm:ss"];
```

Comment: I'm not after the current date, I need the date from my date picker. i.e the date the person chooses. My code returns the right hours value but not the right minutes value. any help?